# C# make ObservableCollection<T> in Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, observablecollection, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to do Combobox, which can display some 2 classes,
- Employee
- Employer
Obviously, both classes have the EditAble variable

```
  private ObservableCollection<Employer> _itemsEmployer
  private ObservableCollection<Employee> _itemsEmployee
  public ObservableCollection<T>  Items, where T : Employee, Employer
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemsEmployee;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_itemsEmployee == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _itemsEmployee = value;
        }
    }
```

the Combobox:

```html
<ComboBox x:Name="cbx" 
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
                      TextSearch.Text="EditAble"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsEditable="True" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="EditAble"
                      Text="{Binding AddedText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Canvas.Left="78" Canvas.Top="48" Width="259">
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties cannot define generic constraints. You need to have a base class for Employee and Employer - e.g. Person. This way the collection can hold both Employees and Employers.

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public ObservableCollection<Person> Items
{
    get
    {
        return _persons;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value == _persons)
        {
            return;
        }

        _persons = value;
    }
}
```